# Linux utility to log user commands and screenshots for auditing

Tags: monitoring, audit

I am looking for a utility that I can implement in linux systems to "audit" user commands in the terminals and take intermittent screenshots for auditing in my systems. Is there a solution that is opensource or low cost that can accomplish this?

I thought of just creating a keylogger and screenshot tool to do the trick but was hoping that this exists already to port logs or format them in a viewer. This is more for an internal "audit" and to review commands that we executed not for a security related audit. More for if we want to look back in time to see what and how we did something we can provide a detailed audit for the actions we took, more CYA. Everyone will have root access and these VMs will be wiped on a regular basis.

Comment: For auditing, I have been using Snoopy (  https://github.com/a2o/snoopy ) Opensource. Screenshots : Do you mean Xwindows screenshot ? achieved transparently to users I presume ? : Then I don't know. If you mean tty screenshots then its should be just easy to periodically cat associated backlog from /dev/vcsN

Comment: A better and easier (long term easy, but will take a bit of learning) way, is to write a script to do everything, and to check it into revision control. Or better, see configuration control tools.

Comment: Thanks, ya screenshots and the users know that it is happening. everyone as root/sudo i.e. i dont care about them being able to disable or see it running, they know and will enable it when they start the process. I will take a look at snoopy and mabe just crontab a screenshot utility.